# How do I change value of selected cell on Gridview

Tags: c#

How do I change the value of a selected cell using a button for e.g. changing a cell value from 1 to 2

```
int row = 0;
            row = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2;
            dataGridView1["Amount", row].Value = Keytxt.Text;
            Keytxt.Clear();
```

this is my current solution but it only changes the value of the last cell in the column

Comment: So it is changing the correct collumn, but you cannot get it to select a specific row in the gridview?

Comment: yeah i need it to select a specific cell in a coloumn and row

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change it using button and textBox try this code,but at the first take row and cell number from user like this...

```
private void button1_click(object sender,Eventargs e){
  int rowIndex = int.Parse(txtRowIndex.Text);
  int cellIndex = int.Parse(txtCellIndex.Text);
  //but here you should validate that textBoxs of row and cell index is only numeric or you can use numericUpDown it will be super easy to use
  dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex-1].Cells[cellIndex-1].value = Keytxt.Text;
  Keytxt.Clear();
}
```